# Why does MySQL allow duplicate values in enum declarations

Tags: mysql, enums

I just stumbled over the fact that MySQL allows duplicate enum values.

Like in `en enum('a','a','b','c') NOT NULL)`

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Its because the way MYSQL actually handles ENUM is by INDEX.

So to MYSQL....

```
 ('a','a','b','c')
```

Actually equals

```
 (0,1,2,3)
```

[See ENUM explanation here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)

And some reasons why to avoid it...if possible, specially if using it as a reference field

[Avoid ENUM](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am clear about what happens. But this does not explain why MySQL did choose to not choke on this definition. I also disagree about the avoid ENUM in every situation.